How do I send a local file attachment on Expo Notifications IOS Attachments?
Similar to UNNotificationAttachment failing to attach image but Expo specific.
Based on the question I refered, it supposedly needs to have a separate file.  So what I did was.
  const [localAssets] = useAssets(localAttachments ?? []);
  const [assets, setAssets] = useState<Asset[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    (async () => {
      if (!localAssets) {
        return;
      }
      const uuid = Crypto.randomUUID();
      const nextAssets = _.cloneDeep(localAssets.filter((it) => it.downloaded));
      for (const asset of nextAssets) {
        const tempLocalUri = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}${asset.hash}.${uuid}.${asset.type}`;
        await FileSystem.copyAsync({
          from: asset.localUri!,
          to: tempLocalUri,
        });
        
        asset.localUri = tempLocalUri;
      }
      if (mounted) {
        setAssets(nextAssets);
      }
    })();
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [localAssets]);

Where I made a copy of the asset to anotehr location and updated the localUri value.  Then I assemble the data send the notification using these useMemo and callback
  const attachments = useMemo<
    Notifications.NotificationContentAttachmentIos[]
  >(() => {
    if (!assets) {
      return [];
    }
    return assets
      .filter((it) => it)
      .map((it) => ({
        identifier: it.hash,
        type: `public.${it.type}`,
        typeHint: `public.${it.type}`,
        url: it.localUri,
        hideThumbnail: false,
      }));
  }, [assets]);

  const content = useMemo<Notifications.NotificationContentInput>(
    () => ({
      ...notificationPayload,
      attachments: attachments,
    }),
    [notificationPayload, attachments],
  );

  const onSendNotification = useCallback(() => {
    (async () => {
      const request: Notifications.NotificationRequestInput = {
        content: content,
        trigger: {
          date: Date.now() + 2_000,
        },
      };
      try {
        console.debug(attachments);
        await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync(request);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [content]);

The result is the following debug which shows a UUID and is a file URI.  I also have an <Image /> that confirms that it renders as an image.
[{"hideThumbnail": false, 
  "identifier": "633435dcb418833920a16771610ca404", 
  "type": "public.png", 
  "typeHint": "public.png", 
  "url": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/110DC7BD-A51E-44D2-A072-8C75BC8F1E3E/Library/Caches/633435dcb418833920a16771610ca404.3acf6d50-e0f0-4d5e-ad55-13b030479460.png"}]

and error message

[Error: Failed to schedule notification. Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=100 "Invalid attachment file URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid attachment file URL}]

Also attempting to use react-native-fs to provide a TempDirectoryPath and copying does not work either.
const tempLocalUri = `file://${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}${asset.hash}.${uuid}.${asset.type}`;

let target = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}${asset.hash}.${uuid}.${asset.type}`;
if (await RNFS.exists(target)) {
  await RNFS.unlink(target);
}
await RNFS.copyFile(
  asset.localUri!.substring('file://'.length),
  target,
);
asset.localUri = tempLocalUri;

Code at https://github.com/trajano/expo-experiments/blob/test-expand-idea/packages/my-app/src/stories/Notification.stories.tsx

Maybe try using FileSystem.temporaryDirectory or  FileSystem.documentDirectory and see if it works. Expo is picky when it comes to directories, and also mime types.

I'm looking at the console logs at the moment but I noticed this

Error opening file for attachment URL: fileURL=, bundleIdentifier=, fileHandleCreationError=(null)

seems to be missing  the URL

The error eludes to notifications not being able to access the cache directory.

I tried documentDirectory still no luck, FYI expo does not expose TempDirectory.
With notifee, I did find that it is sending a proper file URI when using the requires method

However, when I tried to pass a file in (doc/cache) it shows fileURI as empty with notifee

Good to know. The only other thing I can imagine is that the file is not there when the notification actually tries to attach it. So perhaps if you move the notification scheduling inside the useEffect after the files have been copied and verified with FileSystem.getInfoAsync. Also remove TypeHint, as it shouldn't be needed and can apparently cause issues.

Technically it should be verified as the useEffect updates the state and it does list it correctly before I send the actual message by clicking the callback from the button.
Also even with react-native-fs to get the TempDirectoryPath and the slight changes for it, it yields the same results.  I think it may be a native code bug on Expo

One other thing I just realized is that maybe it's getting confused by the multiple dots in the filename, so maybe try ${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}${asset.hash}_${uuid}.${asset.type}

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
